# Tagging Software that stores and reads tags relative to location of tagged file

Tags: windows-7

Does any tagging software exist for Windows that stores tags relative to the tagged files such as within a directory or sub-directory of where the file being tagged is stored?

For example:

The files being tagged:

```
    d:\Google Drive\Foo\file_being_tagged.txt
    d:\Google Drive\Foo\Bar\second_file_being_tagged.txt
```

Location of sub-directories storing the tag information:

```
    d:\Google Drive\Foo\.tags\*
    d:\Google Drive\Foo\Bar\.tags\*
```

Comment: Was hoping for something with this capability so that it could be used on multiple machines in conjunction with Google Drive or Dropbox.